# Display data in jComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am trying to pass data from a db in another class into JFrame in jcombobox but only the last row is displayed. Below is a sample code:

Class A...

```
public String jcbNames() {
    try {
        con = connCC.getDBconnection();
        stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("Select customerName From appointment");

        while (rs.next()) {
            customer = (rs.getString(1));
        }
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Appointment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return customer;
}
```

Class JFrame...

```
private void jCBCustomersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    Appointment app = new Appointment();
    this.jCBCustomers.removeAllItems();
    this.jCBCustomers.addItem(app.jcbNames());
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).  But also remember, you're only returning the last "customer" from `jcbNames`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is there you return just one String in your `jcbNames` method , use an arraylist and add all of strings to it and then  return it as a collection of database data.

so change your methods or use this modified methods.

```
public ArrayList<String> jcbNames() {
    try {
        con = connCC.getDBconnection();
        stm = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("Select customerName From appointment");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getString(1));
        }
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Appointment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return list;
}
```

and

```
private void jCBCustomersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    Appointment app = new Appointment();
    this.jCBCustomers.removeAllItems();
    ArrayList<String> list =app.jcbNames();
    for (String str:list){
         this.jCBCustomers.addItem(str);
    }
}
```

and if you don't want to use `this.jCBCustomers.removeAllItems();` to prevent duplicates , use  below code

```
private void jCBCustomersActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {      
    Appointment app = new Appointment();

    // collect all of your current data in jcombobox
    ArrayList<String> current_list = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = this.jCBCustomers.getItemCount(); // get count of them
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        current_list.add((String) this.jCBCustomers.getItemAt(i)); // add them to current list
    }

    // data that returned from database
    ArrayList<String> returned_from_db_list = jcbNames(); // calling jcbNames method

    /*
        for each string that has returned from database , 
        if it doesn't in the current_list 
        you can add it to jcombobox , so ...
    */ 
    for (String str : returned_from_db_list) {
        if ( !current_list.contains(str) ) { // check for existing in the current_list
            current_list.add(str); // adding fresh data to current_list!
            /*
                or you can add them directly to jcombobox and remove above statement.
                this.jCBCustomers.addItem(str); // add updated data to jcombobox
            */
        }
    }

    /* 
        if   ::: you use   current_list.add(str); in above for-each-loop ,
               now you must update jcombobox data !
        else ::: remove below loop.
    */
    for (String singleStr : current_list) {
        this.jCBCustomers.addItem(singleStr); // add updated data to jcombobox
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked but how do i stop jcombobox from duplicates because if i leave the this.jcb.removeAll () it selects only the first one and if i take it out, it creates duplicates.

Comment: @Meli , i updated my answer , check the last part of it to do this,